# What web architecture is used in Blizzard's Battle.net?

Tags: web-applications, architecture

Blizzard Entertainment uses Battle.net website for managing Starcraft, Diablo and Warcraft series. I can't even imagine how many daily hits they get on www.battle.net. But I am very curious what could they use to build such a highly scalable web application? I want to go ahead and guess it's built on top of Django or Google App Engine but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not either of those. It's Java-based.